# Compare join count to another joined column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, group-by, having

I'm trying to conjure up what I think should be a pretty simple query in

Relevant models:

A `Schedule` `has_many` `Events`, and an `Event` `has_many` `attendees`. **I want to get all of the `events` that have less `attendees` than the what the `event`'s `schedule`'s `min_attendees` column specifies.**

```
SELECT "events".* FROM "events"
INNER JOIN "schedules" ON "schedules"."id" = "events"."schedule_id"
INNER JOIN "attendees" ON "attendees"."event_id" = "events"."id"
GROUP BY events.id
HAVING COUNT(attendees.id) < schedules.min_attendee
```

I get the following error when trying the above query:
`ERROR:  column "schedules.min_attendees" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Edit your question and add your query.

Comment: Done! Added the SQL generated by Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by using an aggregation function on it:

```
SELECT "events".*
FROM "events" INNER JOIN
     "schedules"
      ON "schedules"."id" = "events"."schedule_id" INNER JOIN
      "attendees"
      ON "attendees"."event_id" = "events"."id"
GROUP BY events.id
HAVING COUNT(attendees.id) < MIN(schedules.min_attendee)
```

Or, include it in the `group by`:

```
SELECT "events".*
FROM "events" INNER JOIN
     "schedules"
      ON "schedules"."id" = "events"."schedule_id" INNER JOIN
      "attendees"
      ON "attendees"."event_id" = "events"."id"
GROUP BY events.id, schedules.min_attendee
HAVING COUNT(attendees.id) < schedules.min_attendee
```

Comment: That was nice and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you not put aggregate function near schedules.min_attendee then it should be present in group by else not needed.

This might helps you

```
SELECT "events".* FROM "events"
INNER JOIN "schedules" ON "schedules"."id" = "events"."schedule_id"
INNER JOIN "attendees" ON "attendees"."event_id" = "events"."id"
GROUP BY events.id
HAVING COUNT(attendees.id) < MAX(schedules.min_attendee)
```

You ca use MAX or MIN because for each row it will varies.
Whatever the columns you are using to SELECT that must be in the  GROUP BY clause otherwise it will throw error(It must be appear in group by clause or agg f'n)